# Optimizing Video for PageSpeed

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, pagespeed

Is anyone aware of best practices for using video on websites and minimizing the impact on PageSpeed? Currently using embedded YouTube videos, but would consider self-hosting to lesson the impact. Also open to other video streaming solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, browsers load video last.  That way the large video files do not block the html, CSS, JS, fonts etc. needed to render the page. But there are e few things you can do to optimise your videos:

- If your video is in an iframe - you might consider lazy loading the iframe. https://addyosmani.com/blog/native-iframe-lazy-loading/
- If you are using a video streaming method, you can defer the loading of the JavaScript player - while will load the video after all other rendering activities are completed.
- Consider the size of your video.  Look at the bitrate, the dimensions (use JS to serve different sized videos for mobile v. desktop, if possible).
- YouTube might work well, but IIRC, you're looking at 8 additional domains (DNS lookup, SSL handshake...), and at ~1 MB of additional "stuff" (fonts, CSS, Javascript etc.) added your page to play the video.
- [adaptive bitrate streaming](https://api.video/what-is/adaptive-bitrate-streaming) - where the size is optimized to the screen & network connection. This is built into YouTube, but there are a lot of providers (api.video, Mux, etc.) that also do this (and you can also roll your own, if desired).